# Problem with Query Parser for Lucene.Net

Tags: parsing, lucene.net

I have a word ***multi-strat*** as my search term. When I query it using query parser the parsing term becomes ***multi strat*** and does not retrieve the right hit count. How will I be able to resolve it making the "-" symbol be included in searching and parsing? thanks for the help in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use an analyzer which does not break up strings on hyphens. The most simple one is the KeywordAnalyzer, which doesn't break up strings at all, neither does it change the casing.

You could wrap it in a PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper if you need to have different analyzers for different fields.

Comment: Hi I tried the keyWordAnalyzer yet it gives me no hit count at all. any help?

Comment: The analyzer at index-time must produce the same tokens as the one used during query-time. Perhaps a WhitespaceAnalyzer that only breaks on whitespaces? Do you need stemming? Case insensitivity?