# How to remove hyphen token in lucene.net

Tags: lucene.net

I'm having problem with hyphen when searching. I thinks its because of the Standard Analyzer that I use.

How can I remove that hypen as part of the standard analyzer tokens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with Query Parser for Lucene.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906611/problem-with-query-parser-for-lucene-net)

Answer (score 1):

The `StandardAnalyzer` does indeed break up words with hyphens. What type of data are you indexing? Can you change the analyzer to something else? The `KeywordAnalyzer` wont break up words at all, and the `WhitespaceAnalyzer` will only break on whitespace characters (spaces, newlines, tabs, ...)

You can use the `PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper` if you need to use several analyzers within a document/query.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Tokenizer would fit your criteria.
Please refer, http://karticles.com/NoSql/lucene_custom_tokenizer.html